# Math Puzzle - What am I?

Tags: number-theory

I am X. I was roaming around some place and found another X. We got attracted. Got into some operation and generate Y.

> At first Y is 0

Me and my X got together now and went to roam the places.

> We are now 2X

We found the group of X with the same number of members as ours and also got into some private operation and got another Y.

> We have Y+1

Now, we  all X's got together and the same process happened, got Y and again went around with all the X's.

Now tell me What am I?

Comment: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Sbe gur svefg cneg, gur bcrengvba pbhyq or "fhogenpgvba" fvapr K-K=0 juvpu jbhyq rdhny L va gung pnfr.$]$

Comment: Time for a hint, please.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> **a vector**, roaming somewhere such as the plane.

At first Y is 0

> You are aligned with and opposite to the other X

We are now 2X

> You are aligned with and in the same direction as the other X

We found the group of X with the same number of members as ours and also got into some private operation and got another Y.

> You’ve engaged in matrix operations, maybe multiple times.